# Vue.js - using functions in component methods

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, hoisting

I have a vue2 component, where some methods are pretty long with a lot of callbacks and I would like to structurize it better. I try to follow the guidelines as per [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/) but things don't look that easy within vue method.

Below is the sample of where I am at the moment, it works, but I am confused about the following:

1. [Function hoisting](https://gist.github.com/maxogden/4bed247d9852de93c94c) doesn't seem to work here, I need to define my functions first before I run them otherwise, it triggers an error. Why is that, am I missing something here?
2. When I define inner functions like this, I lose the "this" bound to Vue component in them. I fix it by the `.bind(this)` after the function definition, it works but looks rather obscure. Is there any better way to define a utility function within methods while still keeping the context of "this"?
3. Is this generally adding functions into method a good approach in Vue? I know I could make them sibling methods directly in `methods: {}` object and that resolves most of my issues, but as they are only relevant to the `saveFavourites()` method and not to anything else in the component, wrapping them within looks cleaner to me?

Thanks so much

```
methods: {
    saveFavourites() {
        var promptName = function() {
            return this.$swal({
                text: 'Enter name'),
                content: 'input',
                button: {
                    text: 'Save'),
                    closeModal: true,
                },
            })
        }.bind(this);

        var storePlan = function(name) {
            if(!name || (name = name.trim()) === '' ) return;
            axios.post('/api/user-store-daily-favourites', { meals: this.mealIds, name: name })
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.data.status === 'success') {
                        this.$emit('dailyFavouritesUpdated');
                    }
                });
        }.bind(this);

        // running it - if I move this above functions definitions, I get error
        promptName()
            .then( (name) => storePlan(name) );
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question 1, hoisting only applies to function declarations, not function expressions. Compare:

```js
// Expression
var promptName = function() {
```

to:

```js
// Declaration
function promptName() {
```

For further reading see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

For question 2, using `bind` is fine but you may find it easier to use arrow functions instead, which preserves the surrounding `this` value.

```js
var promptName = () => {
  return this.$swal({
    ...
  })
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

For question 3, that seems like a matter of personal preference but generally I would move them to separate Vue `methods`. You have the usual trade offs to consider. Perhaps you feel the indirection is too high a price to pay and you'd rather keep all the code in one place. That's fine.

In this specific case I suggest you look into `async`/`await` instead of using all those extra functions. However, a word of caution, make sure you understand promises well before trying to use `async`/`await` as most problems with `async`/`await` come from not understanding the underlying mechanism used to implement it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

The `async`/`await` version would look something like this:

```js
async saveFavourites() {
  const name = await this.$swal({
    text: 'Enter name',
    content: 'input',
    button: {
      text: 'Save',
      closeModal: true,
    },
  });

  if(!name || (name = name.trim()) === '' ) return;

  const response = await axios.post('/api/user-store-daily-favourites', {
    meals: this.mealIds,
    name: name
  });

  if(response.data.status === 'success') {
    this.$emit('dailyFavouritesUpdated');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just wondering - if I use function declaration to allow hosting as per 1, can I still use the arrow syntax or use .bind?

Comment: @Ziki If you use a function declaration then it can't be an arrow function. Using `bind` would also be tricky as you couldn't just tag it on the end of the declaration: putting `bind` on the end would immediately make it an expression, not a declaration. Invoking the function using `call` would work to set the `this` value, though it'd be simpler to use the `const that = this` trick in the surrounding scope and use `that` inside the function. Just to be clear, I wasn't advocating the use of function declarations, merely explaining why hoisting doesn't apply with your original code.